# API Gateway use of persistant connection with http 2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have multiple API with API Gateway in front of lambdas, and I want to improve speed by keeping the connection open between calls.

I know I can achieve this by using WebSocket but is it possible with plain Http 2.0 ?

If a client open a https connection with the API Gateway, can it it keep it open and send multiple request over it?
I can't find doc about this, if you have any I would be glad.